# Cell changes x-coordinate after rotaion in mxgraph.How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

After rotating a cell in mxgraph it changes its x-coordinate. Even if I move the cell to the position where it was before rotation (I mean match the left corner before and after rotation) the x-coordinate in geometry of the cell shows a completely different x coordinate.

Look at these 4 cells:

```
<mxCell id="116" style="shape=inner_wall_h;bottom=bottom;;fillColor=#cbccd8;;strokeColor=#cbccd8;rotation=90;" vertex="1" parent="1">
  <mxGeometry x="196.43333435058594" y="372.6499938964844" width="100" height="12" as="geometry"/>
</mxCell>
<mxCell id="118" style="shape=inner_wall_h" vertex="1" parent="1">
  <mxGeometry x="240.43333435058594" y="430.6499938964844" width="100" height="12" as="geometry"/>
</mxCell>
<mxCell id="119" style="shape=inner_wall_h;rotation=0;" vertex="1" parent="1">
  <mxGeometry x="240" y="315" width="100" height="12" as="geometry"/>
</mxCell>
<mxCell id="122" style="shape=inner_wall_v;rotation=90;" vertex="1" parent="1">
  <mxGeometry x="196.43333435058594" y="486.0500030517578" width="100" height="12" as="geometry"/>
</mxCell>
```

cell 116 and 122 are vertical and cell 118 and 119 are horizontal.Although their left side are aligned , they show different values of x.

[image: 4 cellss]

Comment: So what's the problem? 1. The coordinates are as if there is no rotation, top-left corner of the shape. 2. The rotation is performed relative to the shape's center. That's the way mxGraph expresses those things, that's just how it is.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov , I got that. I was actually making a floorplan in which i had to fit windows and doors according to wall. 

I had to write equation for liner graph which calculates the amount of dx given on the length of the shape, so that I could compromise the given result. Anyhow it is working now.

http://wg.rssoft.win/mxgraph-master/